# MacOS source code build, Python 3.11, missing _tkinter support

Tags: python, xcode, macos, cpython, tcltk

I'm attempting to build Python 3.11 from source on MacOS Ventura. The build misses the `_tkinter` module, which I need.

I've compiled my own build of Tcl/Tk 8.6 from source, with Aqua enabled. It is installed in `/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework` and `Tk.framework` respectively.

I've set the `TCLTK_CFLAGS` and `TCLTK_LIBS` environment variables (show below in the configure output).

When I run the configure script, the result is missing `_tkinter` support. `config.log` shows the following

```
configure:13714: gcc -o conftest   -I/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers/ -I/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers/  conftest.c -L/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/ -ltclstub8.6 -L/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/ -ltkstub8.6  >&5
In file included from conftest.c:120:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/tk.h:31:3: error: Tk 8.5 must be compiled with tcl.h from Tcl 8.5
#       error Tk 8.5 must be compiled with tcl.h from Tcl 8.5
```

So the issue the configure script is looking at the Xcode CLT for some reason, and not the new source build in `/Library/Frameworks`.

Is there a way to get the configure script to look directly at my TclTk build?

I tried building and installing Tcl and Tk 8.6 from source, and expected Python's configure script to use them through the `TCLTK_CFLAGS` and `TCLTK_LIBS` environment variables.

Comment: You need *TCL 8.5*, while you have *v8.6*.

Comment: It should be using the ```tk.h``` header included in the Tk v8.6 Framework I installed and pointed to using the ```TCLTK_CFLAGS``` variable.

Comment: Ok, where did you place your *TclTk* builds (includes, libs), and what did you set those 2 variables to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I set `TCLTK_CFLAGS='-I/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers/ -I/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers/'`

I didn't include the Tk includes *e.g.* `TCLTK_CFLAGS='-I/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers/ -I/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Headers/'`.

Rookie mistake. After also setting `TCLTK_LIBS='-L/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/ -lTcl -L/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/ -lTk'` this configuure step completed just fine.